# How to edit files on remote server over ssh and root privileges

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sublime-text-3, raspbian

Setup: local machine has PopOS 20 (based on Ubuntu 20), remote server is running Raspbian Stretch.

I have been editing files on the remote server from the terminal, over `ssh` and with `nano`, but I'm starting to find this set up quite laborious. I have found different solutions on-line:

- I connected the remote server to the local machine's file manager, which proved straightforward and convenient but does not allow me to edit files that require sudo privileges
- I found [the `RemoteSubl` plugin](https://github.com/randy3k/RemoteSubl) for Sublime Text, a text editor that I know well and find very comfortable, but I cannot find a way to edit files with root privileges.

Is there a way to gain root privileges on either of those solutions? Or are there any alternative you would suggest as optimal in terms of security and usability?

Comment: My typical solution: SSH into remote with a `-R` reverse tunnel, then SSH back as root. You now can SFTP being root on the remote end.

Comment: Are you root on the remote :) ? You can sftp directly root@remote IF you enabled sshRootLogin, with key, for instance (and security…)

Comment: @EugenRieck Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it, although it seems quite confusing for now. Do you think that this would be safer than simply connecting as root from local to remote? @GaétanRYCKEBOER I can connect with ssh://regularUser@remoteServer, but not with ssh://root@remoteServer. I might be able to enable root login over ssh in the `sshd_config` file but I wonder if that is a good idea and there are no safer solutions.